# Enabling scheb_2fa verification only for ROLE_ADMIN

Tags: symfony

At the moment, my double authentication is working, but it is required for both ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN. I would like to know if anyone has an idea or if there is already a solution to enable it only for ROLE_ADMIN.

Here is my scheb_2fa.yaml :

```
# See the configuration reference at https://symfony.com/bundles/SchebTwoFactorBundle/6.x/configuration.html
scheb_two_factor:
    security_tokens:
        # Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken
        - Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Token\PostAuthenticationToken
    email:
        digits: 6
        enabled: true
        sender_email: support@e-testing.fr
        sender_name: Support  # Optional
        template: security/confirmCode.html.twig
```

Here is my security.yaml :

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            entry_point: App\Security\UserAuthenticator
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\UserAuthenticator

            form_login:
            # "app_login" is the name of the route created previously
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
                enable_csrf: true
                default_target_path: user_liste
                

            logout:
                path: app_logout
                target: app_login
            
            two_factor:
                auth_form_path: 2fa_login
                check_path: 2fa_login_check
                
            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
         - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
         - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
         - { path: ^/2fa, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_2FA_IN_PROGRESS }
```

Here is my routes/scheb_2fa.yaml :

```
2fa_login:
    path: /2fa
    defaults:
        _controller: "scheb_two_factor.form_controller::form"

2fa_login_check:
    path: /2fa_check
```

I tried to create an event listener but in vain.

Comment: The [documentation is here](https://symfony.com/bundles/SchebTwoFactorBundle/6.x/index.html). You should look into creating a [custom provider](https://symfony.com/bundles/SchebTwoFactorBundle/6.x/providers/custom.html) class in which you can use the *beginAuthentication* method, the method gives you access to `AuthenticationContextInterface $context` and this has the *User* object. You can check the users role here and return true if they are an admin or false for any other role.